# Second view with ViewModel doesn't refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I've got this funny case:
A Page of a quite big application has its own ViewModel. A part of the data comes from a totally different Manager class. My ViewModel has access to this data. Everytime the manager class updates a value, it sends a Mediator message.
The ViewModel gets the message and calls `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ManagerdataData))`. The ManagerData Property has only a getter to get `Manager.Data`. So the Page updates its stuff. The system works so far.

Now I open a MessageBox-thing (it's a `System.Window`) that gets `MessageBox.DataContext = this.ViewModel`. For the UI it also works. All my ManagerData gets loaded and displayed all across the differend Bindings.
But:
OnPropertyChanged seems to have no effect.
The Page does refresh everytime this special Mediator-Message comes from the Manager and then the ViewModel rund the OnNotificationChanged, the Binding-values get re-loaded and get new data from the Manager. But the MessageBox doesn't although it has the same ViewModel.

Does anybody has an Idea of how this is possible?

I thought, maybe it's another instance (a copy) of my ViewModel. So I ask whether a popup is shown, get the topmost Window of the correct type and try to call the method that contains those OnNotificationChanged values. First it crashed because I was in the wrong thread. Using a dispatcher leads to freezes of the whole application.

Any idea? Copying code is... not easy as the project is quite big...

*Edit:*
Okay, so here's the code:

ViewModel:

```
// Inside the constructor. Registers for Mediator-message. The manager sends it when a value is set.
Mediator.Register(MediatorMessage.BackendServerCheckRefreshed, () => RefreshServerCheckUi());

// Method of the Mediator Message
public void RefreshServerCheckUi()
{
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackendServers));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackendServersCommonStatus));
}

// Properties that get stuff from the manager
public BackendServerStatus BackendServersCommonStatus
{
    get
    {
        return backendServerManager.CommonStatus;
    }
}

public BackendServer[] BackendServers
{
    get
    {
        return backendServerManager.BackendServers;
    }
}
```

The UI of this page:

```
<!--Style definition-->
<Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="BackendServerAvailability">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BackendServersCommonStatus}"
                     Value="{x:Static server:BackendServerStatus.NotAvailable}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="inactive.png" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BackendServersCommonStatus}"
                     Value="{x:Static server:BackendServerStatus.Available}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="active.png" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="default.png" />
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>

<!--Image-->
<Image Style="{StaticResource BackendServerAvailability}" />
```

This Binding works. When the value is refreshed, it sends the Mediator Message, this calls `OnPropertyChanged` and then the Icon gets its image.

Now the tricky part:

```
// This is how I call the MessageBox from the ViewModel
this.MessageService.ShowBackendServerCheckInfo(this);
```

The MessageBoxService:

```
// All MessageBoxes are created like this.
public void ShowBackendServerCheckInfo(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    Action action = new Action(() =>
    {
        var args = new MessageBoxEventArgs()
        {
            View = new BackendServerCheckMessageBox(),
            ViewModel = viewModel
        };

        OnNewMessageBox(this, args);
    });
    this.ShowMessageBox(action);
}

// And then called like this:
private void ShowMessageBox(Action action)
{
    /* We need to create the view in the same thread as main application. */
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
}
```

Finally in the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private async void MessageService_OnNewMessageBox(object sender, MessageBoxEventArgs e)
{
    // Some Semaphore work here..

    var messageBox = e.View;
    messageBox.DataContext = e.ViewModel;
    messageBox.Owner = this;

    messageBox.ShowDialog();

    // Release Semaphore
}
```

The MessageBox UI:

```
<ItemsControlItemsSource="{Binding BackendServers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Stackpanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Url}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Port}" />
                <Image Style="{StaticResource BackendServerAvailability}" />
            </Stackpanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

        <!--Buttons-->
<Stackpanel>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource SimpleButtonStyle}"
            Command="{Binding CloseBackendServerCheckCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=BackendServerMsgBox}">
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="2" FontSize="14"
                   Text="{x:Static const:Resources.ButtonOk}" />
    </Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource SimpleButtonStyle}"
            Command="{Binding RestartBackendServerCheckCommand}">
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="2" FontSize="14"
                   Text="{x:Static const:Resources.ButtonRefresh}" />
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

So this was all the relevant code. When the bindings didn't work, I had no values at all and the buttons wouldn't work. The Close-Button sends its `Window` as argument and then the args-Window-Object will be Closed. If the Bindings and stuff don't work, nothing would happen.
I fixed it so far. Now I see all my values. But when the backgroundcheck sends a message that one Server is not available the Popup-Image does not refresh while the Application-Image does.

My guess is that passing all that stuff as EventArgs might make some copies and so the Binding to the correct ViewModel instance gets lost... So I would make anexception for this popup and create it directly in my ViewModel. Anyways it is more than any "usual" popup that just throws something at you and you click it away with "okay". It's more complex in this case.

*Edit2:*
Aaaand calling the MessageBox directly from the ViewModel didn't change a thing. It doesn't work. Is it a problem having more than 1 Bound View?

*Edit3:*
Okay, it actually does work, when I have an instance of the popup and re-set the DataContext from the ViewModel. So I have to find a nice way to get or keep the instance...

Comment: The output window of visual studio would probably give you the answer I think. We can't help you without a code sufficient to replicate the behavior.

Comment: What could be in the output window? I thought this might be more a bunch of theoretical questions: do you think the viewmodel instance is just copied to datacontext?

Comment: *If* you've accurately represented the way the viewmodel is assigned to MessageBox.DataContext, the copy thing seems unlikely. But it's hard to say much to somebody who says, in essence, "I won't show you any of my code. Please reconstruct everything it does." What's happening is clearly possible, because it's happening. My first wild guess would be that your problem lies in something you've absolutely ruled out because you just know it can't possibly be the case. It's probably not something exotic. It's probably a conventional bug that you find by following everything from point A to point Z.

Comment: @ecth binding errors perhaps

Answer (score 0):

So after fiddeling around I have a dirty solution:

```
// Only if the Popup is shown
if (isShowingBackendServerMessageBox)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // Get the frontmost Window
        var messageBox = Application.Current.Windows
            ?.OfType<BackendServerCheckMessageBox>()
            ?.FirstOrDefault();

        // If it is the searched MessageBox, reload all Bindings.
        if (messageBox != null)
        {
            messageBox.DataContext = null;
            messageBox.DataContext = this;
        }
    }));
}
```

I don't like this type of code. But this works and refreshes when I need it to. If anyone has a better idea, you're welcome.